# Naming variables at runtime

Tags: java, arraylist

I am tweaking some XML files and setting up some relation out of the values retrieved. While doing that I have the following need:

I have a string such as `String nextrelation`, the value of which is derived during runtime (extracted from the xml). Now, is it possible to have an `ArrayList` like this:

```
ArrayList<String> nextrelation(value of the string) = new ArrayList<>();
```

Somewhat like reflection? (If I am making some sense :)).

Kindly suggest the way out; I hope there would be some way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Variable names are merely a convenience for the programmer and are not even kept track of after your code is compiled. Consequently, it is not possible to name variables "dynamically" like that. You can try using a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) to store the identifier-value pairs instead:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(nextrelation, new ArrayList<String>());
...
```

Now, to retrieve the list that `nextrelation` corresponds to, you can use `map.get(nextrelation)`.

Answer (score 0):

craeta a HashMap and use it like following :

```
HashMap<String,List<String>> hm = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
```

then you can use it in a following way in your program :

```
hm.put(nextrelation(value of the string),List<String>);
```

and

```
hm.get(nextrelation(value of the string));
```